# I have too many versions of python, and need help making ipython3 connected to a different version

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I use the terminal to run everything. I have multiple Python verisons. Python3.10 is saved in both /usr/local/bin/3.10 and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10. 3.12 is in
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin/python. 'where Python' command gives 3.12, ipython3 also refers to 3.12 but I can not install any packages using pip for 3.12. I get the error: externally-managed-environment. Is the only option left to use the virtual environment on mac? Also, how can I make 3.10 default for ipython3? Thanks in advance.

Update: I found that I had installed ipython again using brew when i downloaded 3.12. Now i uninstalled this ipython version and installed it for python3.10. The issue I have now is how to manage so many python versions? Is it possible to only keep one and make it the default one. How can I upgrade a version because I am scared that upgrading 3.10 will ruin the code I needed for a project. Thank you!

Comment: have you looked into environments and tools to manage these?
I can recommend anaconda or mininconda. Both basically do the same, anaconda just comes with a huge library where a lot of packages are allrdy installed.